# Increment a number in the "search and replace" function in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got a big file with a regex filter. I'm converting it from a system to another, but it needs some modification.

Right now it looks like this:

```
{ 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
```

But first I want to add a line inbetween the `{` and the `chatpattern` by doing the following in the search and replace function:

```
search: { 
replace: { \r "TEXT" \r
```

And here comes the problem, after the first line I want the `"TEXT"` to increment by 1, so it'll be like:

```
{ 
"TEXT1"
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}

{ 
"TEXT2"
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}

{ 
"TEXT3"
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd use a scripting language to do this

Comment: right time to switch to vim, a better editor. It is an easy task for vim. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl oneliner that does the job:

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/\{/"{\ntext".++$i/e;' in.txt
```

The substitution is done in place.>br>
The original file is saved to `in.txt.back` before processing.
Change the `\n` to whatever you want as line break.

**in.txt before:**

```
{ 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
{ 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
{ 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
```

**in.txt after:**

```
{
text1 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
{
text2 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
{
text3 
"chatpattern" "MY REGEX FILTER"
}
```